# Why am I getting, "incompatible types: Bla cannot be converted to Context" in my SQLiteOpenHelper constructor?

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-sqlite, sqliteopenhelper

I'm implementing SQLite functionality into my Android project, using [this tutorial](http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/An_Android_SQLite_Database_Tutorial).

I've got this SQLiteOpenHelper code:

```
public class HHSSQLiteHandler extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "HHS.db";
    private static final String TABLE_VENDORS = "vendors";

    public static final String COLUMN_ID = "_id";
    public static final String COLUMN_VENDORID = "vendorId";
    public static final String COLUMN_COMPANYNAME = "companyName";

    public HHSSQLiteHandler(Context context, String vendor,
                       SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory factory, int company) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, factory, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }
    . . .
```

...but trying to instantiate that class this way:

```
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
    try {
        JSONArray jsonArr = new JSONArray(result);
        for (int i = 0; i < jsonArr.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject jsonObj = jsonArr.getJSONObject(i);
            String vendorId = jsonObj.getString("vendorId");
            String companyName = jsonObj.getString("companyName");
            // Prepare for writing to db
            Vendor vend = new Vendor();
            vend.setVendorId(vendorId);
            vend.setCompanyName(companyName);
            HHSSQLiteHandler sqliteHandler = new HHSSQLiteHandler(this, null, null, 1);
            sqliteHandler.addVendor(vend);
        }
    } catch (JSONException j) {
        System.out.println(j.getMessage());
        Log.i("jsonEx", j.getMessage());
    }
}
```

...gives me, "error: incompatible types: MainActivity.GetVendorsTask cannot be converted to Context" on the "HHSSQLiteHandler sqliteHandler = new HHSSQLiteHandler(this, null, null, 1);" line.

What is it expecting, exactly? What do I pass it to appease it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`this` in a nested class refers to the nested class instance (`GetVendorsTask`), not to the outer class instance (`MainActivity`). Qualify it with e.g. `MainActivity.this` to refer to the outer class instance, and in case it is a `Context` (such as an `Activity`), it will work.